# Not able to load msnbc.com. Weird timeouts. Is my router to blame?

Tags: router, networking

And everything has been taking a long time to connect the past couple days.
Wireless is working for msnbc.com and other site just fine though.

Below is what a log for tracert for www.msnbc.com.
Any clues in it?

```
Tracing route to msnbc.com [207.46.245.60]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2   165 ms    43 ms    43 ms  eugn-dsl-gw08-200.eugn.qwest.net [67.42.192.200]

  3   217 ms   229 ms   192 ms  eugn-agw1.inet.qwest.net [67.42.193.57]
  4    90 ms    92 ms    97 ms  eug-core-01.inet.qwest.net [205.171.150.57]
  5   123 ms   124 ms   127 ms  sea-core-02.inet.qwest.net [67.14.1.198]
  6   143 ms   141 ms    49 ms  sea-edge-01.inet.qwest.net [205.171.26.134]
  7   139 ms    51 ms    49 ms  65.116.65.166
  8   190 ms    63 ms    50 ms  ge-0-3-0-54.wst-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.46.
33]
  9   132 ms    50 ms    49 ms  ge-0-2-0-0.tuk-64cb-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.47.7
0]
 10    88 ms     *      301 ms  ten2-4.tuk-76c-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.46.23]
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25
```

not sure on how to make this look good on here. Blockquote tags did not help.

Here is the tracert for the wireless connection, coming from the *same* router (different computer though)

```
Tracing route to msnbc.com [207.46.150.20] over a maximum of 30 hops:

1     1 ms     4 ms     2 ms  qwestmodem.domain.actdsltmp [192.168.0.1]
2   185 ms   207 ms   178 ms  eugn-dsl-gw08-200.eugn.qwest.net [67.42.192.200]

3   169 ms   191 ms   226 ms  eugn-agw1.inet.qwest.net [67.42.193.57]
4    44 ms    52 ms    48 ms  eug-core-01.inet.qwest.net [205.171.150.57]
5    87 ms    86 ms    92 ms  sea-core-02.inet.qwest.net [67.14.1.198]
6    55 ms    51 ms    49 ms  sea-edge-01.inet.qwest.net [205.171.26.134]
7   110 ms   115 ms    51 ms  65.116.65.166
8   204 ms   196 ms    85 ms  ge-0-3-0-54.wst-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.46.33]
9   131 ms    51 ms    51 ms  ge-1-0-0-0.cpk-64c-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.43.218]
10    90 ms    58 ms    49 ms  ten3-4.cpk-76c-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.47.193]
11    82 ms    54 ms    50 ms  10.22.0.14
12     *     10.22.0.10  reports: Destination net unreachable.
```

Comment: Thank for making that much more readable! How did you do that?

Comment: 4 spaces at the begining of the lie tells markdown that that line is a 'codeblock'

Comment: Highlight the text and press Ctrl-k or click the "101010" button for tagging text as code (kode?).

Comment: @Zypher: Yeah, that, too.

Answer (score 1):

First, it could be a problem with the LAN side network port on the modem. Get a replacement unit in from your ISP and see if that helps.

However, it's worth noting that I had a very similar problem on a business class DSL line that involved not being able to access MSNBC.com, Microsoft.com and a few other sites. I ended up calling my ISP and got an interesting tip: switch my DSL modem from PPPoE to PPPoA. They had very similar problems with some other businesses in the city and that "fixed" it. My contact wasn't a technical person so I wasn't able to get any specific reason as to why that changed things for the better. I know it sounds weird... but that's because it is. =) You might want to give that a try if the modem and your ISP network supports it.

Comment: Does this explain why wirless works with no issues?
I have a tomato firmware router plugged into the modem/router that my ISP gave me and the wireless for that Tomato/Linksys router can get to msnbc fine. 
This just started happening last night.

Comment: Switching from PPPoE to PPPoA gives you a "normal" 1500-byte MTU. This can often avoid path MTU problems.

Comment: @bobber: now that I understand that the wireless is not a function of the modem itself, that indeed does change things. Probably neither of my suggestions are relevant now.

Comment: @Gerald Combs: Thanks for that tip! Any documentation that you're aware of that could school me further in this topic?

Comment: Both my modem and my linksys router have wireless.

Comment: But you're not using the modem's wireless, correct?

Comment: I was. The modem's wireless was able to get to the site just fine. The ethernet was not.

Comment: Hrm. Oh well. No worries now since it seems Zypher has nailed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

MSNBC has DNS round robbin setup, your wireless computer is getting a different response than your non wireless computer. It appears that a router between you and the edge router that services the `207.46.245.60` Address is having issues. while there are no issues with the path to the `207.46.150.20` network. I would try specifying those ips manually in a traceroute and not relying on DNS, if you get the same results - .60 un available - then you'll just have to wait it out.

Comment: I just tried plugging my cord for the computer having problems into the linksys/tomato router and it works. Pretty sweet. :)